# Not all arguments converted during bytes formatting Insert Python

Tags: mysql, python

Estava tentando adicionar valores inteiros com python em um banco de dados mysql com o código seguinte:

```
import MySQLdb
valor1 = input("Digite o primeiro valor: ")
valor2 = input("Digite o segundo valor: ")
conexaoMySQL = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="User",db="Database",passwd="password")
cursor = conexaoMySQL.cursor()
conexaoMySQL.select_db('password')
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Dados (Campo1,Campo2) VALUES(?, ?)', 
(valor1,valor2))
conexaoMySQL.commit()
conexaoMySQL.close()
```

Mas estou recebendo esse erro:

> line 204, in execute
>   query = query % args
>
> TypeError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/hymb/PycharmProjects/PythonDevID01/AppClientPy/pro.py", line 8, in 
>       cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Dados (Campo1,Campo2) VALUES(?, ?)',(valor1,valor2))
>     File "/home/hymb/VirtualDevlopmentPython/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
>       raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
>   MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Em MySQL tenho um banco de dados e uma tabela com dois campos que recebem inteiros

Comment: Você possui 5 `?` na consulta e passa 6 valores...

Comment: Agora que foi ver, Obrigado

Comment: Se você alterar isso na pergunta não irá parar de dar esse erro? A sua pergunta deixará de ter sentido...

Comment: Ainda não está funcionando, já alterei os valores no meu codigo original

Comment: E ocorre exatamente o mesmo erro? Então será melhor elaborar um [mcve] para a pergunta

Comment: Ok, vou tentar fazer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para funcionar o código precisa converter os valores para outro valor interpretável pelo MySQL. Para isso é necessário alterar os pontos de interrogação(?) por %s